# Texblock - Fazer um evento de alteração de texto

Tags: c#, wpf, eventos

Já vi que a propriedade de `TextBlock` não possui um evento quando muda o texto. Existe alguma forma de fazer um evento quando o texto for alterado?

<sup>* Lembrando que é para WPF e não Windows Forms. Essa pergunta é apenas para WPF.</sup>

Comment: E se você utilizasse um TextBox tirando os estilos, deixando-o idêntico ao TextBlock?

Comment: Eu uso `TexBlock` por causa dessa propriedade: `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"`, parece que o `TextBox` não possui essa propriedade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code-behind binding

Utilize um binding para a propriedade `Text` e sete-o no `DataContext` da tela. A partir daí pode usar o `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` e o `TargetUpdated`, assim:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding MeuTexto, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
           TargetUpdated="textBlock1_TextChanged"/>
```

Lá na classe utilize o novo método `textBlock1_TextChanged` para tratar.

## Dependency Property

No construtor da sua classe ou no evento `Loaded`, adicione isso. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233156/6241184)

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor dp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBlock.TextProperty, typeof(TextBlock));

dp.AddValueChanged(textblock_principal, (object a, EventArgs b) =>
{
      // texto alterado!
});
```

- [MSDN: Classe DependencyPropertyDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx)